# VS2012 error setting references to mvvmcross for WP8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mvvmcross

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Tutorial-Part-1) for mvvmcross and I'm trying to get the "Windows Phone UI" project working. However when I try to set references to the mvvmcross binaries, Visual Studio (2012 Premium) displays an error: a reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project.

I am using the mvvmcross binaries from 2013_01_28 as specified in the tutorial and have installed Windows Phone SDK (7.1 and 8.0). I have tried with both WP7.1 and WP8 projects but same error occurs.

Are there perhaps different binaries I should be using for WP8 VS2012?
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you downloaded the files from the Interweb and Windows is protecting you from evil.

Try unblocking the assemblies:

http://pcmusings.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/vs2012-windows-phone-and-the-reference-to-a-higher-version-error/

Comment: {facepalm} You are correct sir! Sometimes I tend to forget the wonders of Windows... Strangely enough VS2012 did not complain at all when I was referencing mvvmcross binaries to my Droid project. Guess Windows considers these binaries much safer ;-)