# Does mvvmcross support windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I'm working my way through the MMVMCross Tip Calculator tutorial.

Got an Android instance up and running and have now turned my attention to Windows Phone 8.

So far, I can't find the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json assembly in the WindowsPhone bin folder, and I'm also having issues with the CreateApp() method not being able to resolve the Core.App class (there are a bunch of suggestions for chasing down the Core namespace but none of them have an App class inside that I can see).

When I comb through the docs it seems WP7 is supported explicitly, but no mention of 8.  Anybody have any luck getting this scenario going?  Is there a hack I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the Nuget package (The HotTuna Startup) in an Andriod project, I was unable to build and was getting the same problem in the CreateApp() where Core is not resolved. I had missed adding the package MVVMCross.Core and MvvmCross - Hot Tuna Libraries (which added the app.cs) to my core PCL library. Those Nuget packages are a great way to get started!

It's obvious now, but maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Windows Phone 8 is supported, but there's no specific extensions for WP8 yet (e.g. we still use the Community C# SQLite code)

The Core.App class should be in your Core/application project. e.g. in the tutorial it's in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/tree/vnext/Sample%20-%20Tutorial/Tutorial/Tutorial.Core

Comment: Also adding a cross ref to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976712/vs2012-error-setting-references-to-mvvmcross-for-wp8 - a recent problem seen in getting up and running

Comment: Thank you!  I could see other people getting up and running, but couldn't quite figure out how :).  Awesome project by the way.  Heard you on DotNetRocks and had to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. Documentation isn't our strong point... nor is nuget... nor is...  oops... we do have strong points somewhere - honest!. If you need quick help, try https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/mvvmcross - otherwise questions here are **perfect**!

Comment: Got my sample running on everything but Touch (no Mac handy).  Only took a few hours once you got my head reshaped on WP8...now on to something tricky.  Very excited!